Streaming text from Firebase Cloud Functions Version 2, Works in emulator, fails when deployed
Our Firebase cloud function looks like:
exports.answers = functions.https.onRequest(req,res)...

const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
                model: "gpt-4",
             {"role": "user", "content": "Tell me something about life etc"}],
                stream: true,
            });
            
            for await(const chunk of stream) {
                res.write(chunk.choices[0]?.delta?.content || '');
            }
.
.
.
res.end();

It works fine and we can listen to stream and displays data as expected but only in firebase functions emulator. When deployed Firebase, it sends data as one big response text. Looks like some sort of buffering on server side. Is there anyway to make it behave the same way as in emulator?
Tried setting different response headers, like no-cache etc.

Cloud Functions doesn't support chunked or streamed responses. The entire output is buffered and sent to the client.  The emulator just doesn't do exactly what the cloud service does because it's not at all the same code and infrastructure.
